# If $A$ generates the $C_0$-semigroup $\{T_t;t\ge0\}$, then $Au=f \Rightarrow u=-\int_0^\infty T_t f dt$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, semigroup-of-operators, elliptic-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $(A,D_A)$ be a linear operator on $X$ which can generate a (contractive, if needed) $C_0$-semigroup $\{T_t;t\ge0\}$, where $D_A\subset X$ is the domain of $A$. The question is the following:

> If $u\in D_A$ and $f\in X$ satisfy the equation
>   $$Au=f,$$
>   then $u=-\int_0^\infty T_t f dt$ ?

If the answer is yes, how to derive this formally? Or can anyone give some hints or reference? If no, can someone give some conditions such that the representation of $u$ hold true? Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{0}^{\infty}T_t fdt = \int_{0}^{\infty}T_t Au dt = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}(T_t u)dt= T_t u|_{t=0}^{\infty}=-u$ iff $T_tu\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: In particular, if the semigroup is contractive and $\mathbf{i}\mathbb R\subset\rho(A)$, then the operator $X\ni f\mapsto-\int_0^\infty T_t fdt\in D(A)$ is (well-defined and) the inverse of $A$.

Comment: @Pedro Why do you need $\mathbf{i}\mathbb R\subset\rho(A)$?

Comment: @Q.Huang In this case $T_tu\rightarrow 0$ for all $u$.

Comment: @Pedro How to derive this? Or could you give some exact reference? Thank you!

Comment: @Q.Huang [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup#Strong_stability) there is a reference (Wikipedia).